# multiple return values in function

Tags: c++, c

I've faced the next one sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// test multiple return                                                                                                                                                             
int foo()
{
    return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
}

// main entry point                                                                                                                                                                 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("foo returns: %d\n", foo());
    return 0;
}
```

compile it, then run:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main
./main
```

The results are confusing me:

```
foo returns: 6
```

The question is: why there is no compile time error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator): the expression `a,b` where `a` and `b` are arbitrary (usually side-effecting) sub-expressions mean: evaluate the left-hand side `a` and discard its result (so `a` is only evaluated for side-effects), then evaluate `b` and give it as result.

You cannot return several things from a *C* function. You should return e.g. an aggregate (usually a `struct`) or a dynamically heap-allocated pointer.

As to the question, why the compiler don't say anything? Because you didn't ask it. You really should compile with `gcc -Wall` (for C code) or `g++ -Wall` (for C++ code), and then you get warnings:

```
 egor7.c: In function ‘foo’:
 egor7.c:6:13: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 egor7.c:6:15: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 egor7.c:6:17: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 egor7.c:6:19: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 egor7.c:6:21: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

Answer (score 11):

In this context:

```
return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

is actually the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). It evaluates everything between the commas in order (left-to-right), and returns the last one.

That's why it returns and prints `6`. **So yes, it's valid code.** That's why there's no compiler error. (Although the `1,2,3,4,5` part doesn't do anything in this case.)

In C and C++, you can't return multiple values. You'd have to use a struct or a class to do that.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, use Clang:

```
$ clang++ -Weverything test.cpp
test.cpp:4:5: warning: no previous prototype for function 'foo' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
int foo()
    ^
test.cpp:6:10: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
         ^
test.cpp:6:12: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
           ^
test.cpp:6:14: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
             ^
test.cpp:6:16: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
               ^
test.cpp:6:18: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  return 1,2,3,4,5,6;
                 ^
6 warnings generated.
```

As the name implies, `-Weverything` activates every single warning available. This way you don't have to remember the groups they are in.

As for the explanations: see Mysticial's answer about the comma operator and its sequencing effects. One useful occurrence of this operator is:

```
std::list<Item> list = /**/;
assert(list.size() >= 10);

auto it = list.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i, ++it) {
  std::cout << "Item " << i << ": " << *it << "\n";
}
```

Note how the 3rd clause of the `for` loop uses the comma operator to do two operations in a single statement.

Of course, such syntax is mostly anecdotical, so people regularly get surprised...